# How to hide form field based on url

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a search form where in normal page, I would like to hide a field with an initial value in it. But in certain page (in Advanced Search), I would like to show the field to the user. How can I get it done in the form init?

eg.
The forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    keyword = forms.CharField(label="Keyword", required=True)
    cat = forms.CharField(required=True, default='1')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['cat'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

The above only hide the 'cat' field. How to I control the field base on the url?
The urls.py:

```
url(r'^advance-search/$', views.AdvancedSearch, name='adv-search'),
```

How to pass the url to the form init? And what parameter should I check to identify if it is the advance search page?

Comment: You could just make a separate form for the advanced search and show which gets displayed in the view.

Comment: I know, but I want to know if there any way that make this works. Plus in certain situation, I may need the request objects to be carry to the advanced search form.